# Python path as a string

Tags: python, path

I am specifying a relative file path using jacaro's [path](https://github.com/jaraco/path.py) module.

How can I get the absolute path from this variable as a string?

```
import path # From https://github.com/jaraco/path.py

path = path.path('~/folder/')
relative_filename = path.joinpath('foo')
# how can I get the absolute path of as a string?
absolute_path = ???
fd = open(absolute_path)
```

Comment: What function needs a string?  By total path do you mean the absolute path like /home/foo/myapp?  Can you show an example?

Comment: Yes, by total path I mean absolute path. The function that needs a string is SFTPClient.open from paramiko module. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: So you need filename to be a string?  As a side note, you're overriding the name path with `path = path('~/folder/')`. A better name would be folder_path = ...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`filename` has a method called [abspath](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) that returns an object with the absolute path.  You can cast that to a string.

```
...
from path import Path
folder_path = Path('/home/munk/folder/')
filename = folder_path.joinpath('foo')
absolute_path = filename.abspath()
print(absolute_path)  #  '/home/munk/folder/foo'
f = open(absolute_path, 'r')
```

UPDATE 2023-03-24: Actually use abspath + use the [up to date path library](https://github.com/jaraco/path)

Comment: Calling str() seems weird to me, I might expect something like what repr() would produce. I would have expected an as_string attribute or something.

Comment: But *abspath* is not used in the example(?).

Comment: why do i only see `.absolute()` method?

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('~/folder/foo')
absolute_path = path.absolute().as_posix()
```

## Python 2

```
import os

absolute_path = os.path.abspath('~/folder/foo').as_posix()
```

Comment: `pathlib.Path.absolute()` doesn't return a string; it returns a `PosixPath`/`WindowsPath` object.